# jquery.load() function cant find directory of my html file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a mvc5 application and I currently have the following solution layout

```
MyApplication
---->**Properties**

---->**References**

---->**App_Data**

---->**Content**
    ---->*HTML*
        ---->TestPage.html
    ---->*JS*
        ---->menu.js
```

And in my javascript file I'm trying to lead the `TestPage.html` onto a div.

```
$('.expandable-item').click(function() {

    $('#menu').load("../HTML/TestPage.html");

});
```

And in my console I just get a basic 404 error stating

`GET http://localhost:50712/HTML/HtmlPage1.html 404 (Not Found)`

So I'm not quite sure how to access that html file.

Comment: Man, I am facing the same problem and the below answer do not helps. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery load method sends http request and does not operate on the file system, so you need change your code to this:

```
$('.expandable-item').click(function() {

    $('#menu').load("/Content/HTML/TestPage.html");

});
```